# Compatibility of C++ program exe

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-studio-2015

These days I'm working on Windows programming.  The following code won't run on another Windows computer, why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    TCHAR tcWindowsPath[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR tcCurrentPath[MAX_PATH];

    GetWindowsDirectory(tcWindowsPath, MAX_PATH);
    GetSystemDirectory(tcCurrentPath, MAX_PATH);

    printf("%s \n", tcWindowsPath);
    printf("%s \n", tcCurrentPath);
    ////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

Comment: what you mean under "not working" ? exe not exec - so provide error code and os version.

Comment: not sure as you haven't told us what is not working, if you receive any error messages ect all you said was that it doesn't work on another computer.....

Comment: If you are compiling a VS 2015 generated standard command line application (with default settings), this won't work as expected on any machine. The wizard generated code defaults to using Unicode, and that is UTF-16LE on Windows, yet your `printf` calls assume ANSI encoding.

Comment: @IInspectable: the simplest solution to that would be to use `_tprintf()` instead, to match the code's use of `TCHAR` variables.  Otherwise, the code should be changed to use `WCHAR` variables with `GetWindowsDirectoryW()`/`GetSystemDirectoryW()` and `wprintf()` (if not `CHAR` variables with `GetWindowsDirectoryA()`/`GetSystemDirectoryA()` and `printf()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choosing the appropriate runtime environment from your project settings:

```
Configuration Propertes -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library
```

will determine if you rely on statically linking your project to the runtime or dynamically linking via DLLs. If you choose to dynamically link to the runtime then those DLLs need to be present on the system you are running on.

Choosing the /MT options will statically link your executable allowing you to run on another system without installing the Visual C++ redistributable run time components. If you choose the /MD options then the system you are running on will need to have this installed. Installing a the redistributables such as the most recent, [Visual C++ Redistributable 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).

[Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/256245/why-are-there-so-many-microsoft-visual-c-redistributables-installed-on-my-pc/) is a decent in detail write up on this.

UPDATE:

In addition to the comment below with static vs dynamic linking... You can set your target platform with:

```
Configuration Properties -> General -> Platform Toolset
```

I am not sure what other computer you are running this on, but if it is XP, 2015 has an option for Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp). Make sure that the platform you are targeting is covered by the your development platform.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770576.aspx) article targets this answer mainly from a .NET perspective but the information is just as relevant.

Comment: thanks for reply. But i wonder is there an another solution about this fact.

Comment: While what you say about static vs dynamic linking is true in general, it doesn't apply in this particular situation because `GetWindowsDirectory()` and `GetSystemDirectory()` are both implemented in `kernel32.dll`, which all versions of Windows have and does not need to be (and should not be) distributed with 3rd party apps.  The problems has to be something else.

Comment: @Remy good point. I updated the answer to also address Platform Toolsets.

Comment: @PaulT: The toolset shouldn't matter much either, since the code is not using any platform-specific APIs.  Unless the project is linking against an RTL library that internally does.

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to start it on another computer. What build is the other system? The platform does matter, I tested it, if I build that with  v140 and run it on XP, it will not run unless I build it with "Windows XP (v140)".